# Custom WPS for GeoServer (overlay of two polygon layers)

Tags: geoserver, java, wps

I am trying to create my own WPS process in Java about overlaying two polygon shapefiles, but I can't figure out how to do it. Here is a code about reading Shapefile and creating buffer around point.

```
public String overlay(String pointString, double distance) {
    String names = "Object:Area of overlay";
        try {
            //read SHP
            ShapefileDataStore sfdt = new ShapefileDataStore(new URL("file:///_ING/geoserver-2.8.0/data_dir/data/sf/restricted.shp"));
            SimpleFeatureSource sfs = sfdt.getFeatureSource("restricted");

            //double distance 1000.0d;
            GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory ();
            String xy [] = pointString.split(" ");
            Point point = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(Double.parseDouble(xy[0]), Double.parseDouble(xy[1])));

            Polygon p1 = (Polygon) point.buffer(distance);

            SimpleFeatureIterator sfi = sfs.getFeatures().features();
            while (sfi.hasNext()) {
                SimpleFeature sf = sfi.next();
                MultiPolygon mp2 = (MultiPolygon) sf.getDefaultGeometry();
                Polygon p2 = (Polygon) mp2.getGeometryN(0);
                Polygon p3 = (Polygon) p2.intersection(p1);
                names = names + "\n" + sf.getAttribute("cat") + ": " + p3.getArea();
            }

        }   catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Process.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        } catch (IOException ex2) {
        Logger.getLogger(Process.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex2);

        }
    return "Objects found: " + names;
}
```

Here is implementation into GeoServer

```
@DescribeProcess (title="overlayWPS", description="Creates buffer around point and overlays it with polygon layer. Returns area of overlay.")
public class OverlayWPS implements GeoServerProcess {

    @DescribeResult(name="result", description="output result")
    public String execute(@DescribeParameter(name="point", description="point") String point, @DescribeParameter(name="distance", description="distance to search") double distance) {
        Process p = new Process();
        return p.overlay(point, distance);
```

I would like to change it get overlay of two separate shapefiles and get overlaid area as third multi-polygon layer.

https://github.com/val0065/dp

Answer (score 3):

As you have figured out there are two distinct steps to building a new WPS process.

1. Build a GeoTools `process` to carry out the actual work
2. Build a GeoServer `WPS wrapper to call that process.

There are two tutorials that walk you through each of those steps, the [GeoTools process tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/process.html) and the [GeoServer WPS service tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/wps-services/implementing.html).

However for your problem you should be able to achieve the requirement of returning the overlap between two shapefile layers using the existing `gs:IntersectionFeatureCollection` process provided by default in the WPS plugin.

Comment: Thanks for tips. And yes, i know there is such a process, but i want to make my own. Its one of the processes i want to chain inside of one "WPS wrapper"